# Delete an array element from a 2d array mongoDB

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express

I want to delete an array from a 2d array from my mongoDB collection.
My Schema looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6218e63e4f9e4efbb05de2bf"),
    "name" : "Toyota",
    "rate" : 50,
    "fine" : 5,
    "datesBooked" : [ 
        [ 
            "2022-02-08", 
            "2022-02-14"
        ], 
        [ 
            "2022-02-16", 
            "2022-02-18"
        ], 
        [ 
            "2022-02-20", 
            "2022-02-22"
        ], 
        [ 
            "2022-02-24", 
            "2022-02-25"
        ], 
        [ 
            "2022-03-01", 
            "2022-03-02"
        ], 
        [ 
            "2022-03-01", 
            "2022-03-02"
        ]
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I would like to find an object with a certain _id and delete a particular element from the datesBooked 2d array. I tried using $pull function but I couldn't get it right. Can someone please tell me how should I be doing this! I'm using express and javascript to do this. Also, I am noob.
Already grateful
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to remove particular element from the 2nd array inside datesBooked array via $pull:

```
 var myVariable="2022-02-14"
 db.collection.update({ "_id": ObjectId("6218e63e4f9e4efbb05de2bf") },
  {
   "$pull": {
     "datesBooked.$[]": myVariable
   }
 })
```

Explained:
You need to use the  [all positional operator $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) ( available since mongodb v3.6) to provide the 2nd array to the $pull operation so it remove the array element with the exact value , in the example this is value "2022-02-14"

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/os8jSd83MJl)

If you need to remove the element with [var1,var2] from first array you need to do with $pull like this:

```
 db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("6218e63e4f9e4efbb05de2bf")
  },
 {
 "$pull": {
  "datesBooked": [
   "2022-02-08",
   "2022-02-14"
  ]
 }
})
```

explained: Pull the array element from the first array

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EQhz3Tr9gLF)

Comment: Hi! can I equate "datesBooked.$[]" to a variable like so? "datesBooked.$[]": variable. Now it is being compared to a constant "2022-02-14". I would like to compare it to a variable. Sorry for asking such a noob question, but I am unable to do that :(

Comment: afcourse you can compare to variable , you can replace with your variable in your javascript ... , updated my answer with variable

Comment: This would remove just one element of the 2d array right? How can I remove both the elements of the array. I would like to remove the entire array form the 2d array which has value = [var1, var2]. Could not do this "datesBooked.$[]": [myVariable1, myVariable2]

Comment: Updated my answer with your second option ...

Answer (score 0):

in Mongodb v4.2+ you can use pipelined updates to achieve this, like so:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
{ _id: id },
[
  {
    $set: {
      datesBooked: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $slice: [
              "$datesBooked",
              index
            ]
          },
          {
            $slice: [
              "$datesBooked",
              index + 1,
              {
                $size: "$datesBooked"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QQAUZjBMbtT)

For older versions this cannot be done in 1 call, you will need to split this into 2 calls separate calls.

-------------------------- EDIT -------------------------------
Here's how to do it with variables:

```
const var1 = "2022-02-20";
const var2 = "2022-02-22";

db.collection.updateOne(
{ _id: id },
[
  {
    $set: {
      datesBooked: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$datesBooked",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $ne: [
                  {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      "$$this",
                      0
                    ]
                  },
                  var1
                ]
              },
              {
                $ne: [
                  {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      "$$this",
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  var2
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_DqWTzCbJLa)

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks a lot for helping here, but could I somehow do this by comparing the array elements to be deleted with a variable and then delete the array element. I would not like to do this for a particular index, but compare it and if it matches the one I want to delete, only then I delete it?

Comment: yes ofcourse it can be done, do you want to specify based on what conditions you'd like it?

Comment: I would like to delete it only when datesBooked[i][0] == variable1 && datesBooked[i][1] == variable2.

Comment: I edited in how to do it, you can actually achieve this in a few different ways. i showed how to use pipelined updates feature with `$filter`.